# batch file for /f delims

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I was sent this script but this gives me a value that should not be

```
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('fastboot oem get_unlock_data 2^>^&1') DO if ("!out!"=="") (set out=%%i) else (set out=!out!%lf%%%i)
set unlockkey=%out:~18,31%%out:~63,31%%out:~108,31%%out:~153,31%%out:~198,7%
ECHO %unlockkey%
pause
```

command by itself gives me a result like this:

```
(bootloader) 3A95030005785963#5A583142323239
(bootloader) 46393400585431303231000000#CEA2
(bootloader) 1CAEF1B646B1C65B3B6B9492C88CFAB
(bootloader) 304FF#8B734A0312000000000000000
(bootloader) 0000000

OKAY [  0.296s]
finished. total time: 0.291s
```

And the batch should give me a result like this:

```
0A40040192024205#4C4D355631323030373731363031303332323239#BD008A672BA4746C2CE02328A2AC0C39F951A3E5#1F532800020000000000000000000000
```

but instead I get this result:

```
al time: 0.291s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "unlockkey="
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('fastboot oem get_unlock_data 2^>^&1') DO if "%%a"=="(bootloader)" set "unlockkey=!unlockkey!%%b"
ECHO %unlockkey%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should produce the result I gather you want.

It's very difficult to know - since the result you show is apparently unrelated to the data provided. There is no `0A40` in your example data.

The variable `lf` isn't set up in your code. It's probably supposed to be a line feed, but there's no apparent reason to be inserting that.

And it's important to provide sufficient of your code to be able to reproduce the problem. The `setlocal` is important, but omitted from your posted code.

Comment: thank you very much exactly what I wanted, and like I said I have no knowledge about it, the lines you gave me are what I wanted